# "ways/steps to increase" And "ways/step to increasing"

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive

**Way** and **step**

I happened to read some sentences containing phrases with two similar forms such as

> Subject Verb `to` Verb...

and

> Subject Verb `to` Verb`-ing`...

I come up examples for each.

> "I find ways to increase my enjoyment in study."

And

> "I find ways to increasing my enjoyment in study."

In what situations each one is correct?

Any explanation in meanings?

***How about the other word "step"?**

> I take steps to increase my enjoyment in study.

and

> I take steps to increasing my enjoyment in study.

**A similar example:**

> Steps to overcoming obstacles

[image: Steps to overcoming obstacles]

Comment: Both of your second options are wrong. We can say _ways **of** increasing_ but not _steps of_ or _steps to increasing_.

Comment: "Steps to overcoming obstacles" is from a book which I currently read. I am quite surprised.

Comment: This is interesting. I think the explanation is that _steps to overcoming obstacles_ uses _step_ in the sense of 'a stage in a process', while _take steps_ has the specific meaning of  'do what is necessary', so their grammatical functions are different.

Comment: @KateBunting I added the souce of "steps to overcoming obstacle".

Comment: Which shows a drawing of actual steps. Take it from me, _I take steps to increasing my enjoyment in study_ is not idiomatic English.

Comment: I definitely believed you. You did provide answers in detail. I was a bit curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I find ways to increase my enjoyment in study. [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

This is a fully grammatical use, which a fluent speaker should understand. Such a speaker might be more likely to say "I have found way..." or "I am finding ways..." but there is nothing with sentence 1.

> 2. I find ways to increasing my enjoyment in study. [image: Red X indicating an incorrect form]

This is not grammatical, or at least is not natural. The form "to increasing" is not used in this construction. "increasing" indicates a process, and so does not fit "I find ways to..." (Increasing cvan also indicate a direction, as "the prices are increasing" but it still does not fit in sentence 2.)

> 3. I take steps to increase my enjoyment in study. [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

This, like sentence 1, is fully grammatical. A fluent speaker would understand and might well say sentence 3.

> 4. I take steps to increasing my enjoyment in study. [image: Red X indicating an incorrect form]

This has much the same problem as sentence 2.  "to increasing" is still not used in this construction, and the change from "find ways" to "take steps"  does not alter that.

> 5. Steps to overcoming obstacles [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

This could be short for

> 5A. Here are some steps to overcoming obstacles. [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

The participle "overcoming" can accept this "to-form" while "increasing" cannot. I find it hard to spell out a reason for this in the form of a concise rule. Perhaps someone else could do so.

> 6. Here are some steps for increasing enjoyment in study [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

by changing the preposition from "to" to "for" and taking the sentence out of the first person, sentence 4 becomes acceptable. A similar transformation on sentence 2 yields:

> 7. Here are some ways for increasing enjoyment in study [image: Green Check indicating acceptable form]

Comment: Examples 5 up to 7 are perfect.

Comment: Define "perfect". As [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ways+for+improving%2Cways+to+improve&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cways%20for%20improving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cways%20to%20improve%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows, native speaker almost always choose to refer to *ways **to improve** things* rather than *ways **for improving** things*. Just because no-one wants to rule it out on *syntactic* grounds doesn't imply the latter form is even "any good", let alone "perfect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I claim only that examples 5A to 7 are grammatically valid, would be understood by a fluent speaker, and not thought particularly odd by such a speaker, not that they are favored by such speakers in general.

Comment: David: Indeed. My only intended response to your actual Answer text here was the upvote itself. I just didn't think it was a good idea to let @Stats Cruncher's "erroneous / questionable" assertion stand. We wouldn't necessarily think the "less favoured" form was "odd", but there's no doubt whatsoever which way most native speakers would jump if required to actually make a choice between the infinitive and continuous verb forms in such contexts.

Comment: As a non-native English speak, I just take baby steps ***to*** improve on my learning outcome.

Comment: May I ask if the related passive is possible: 1a. Steps / ways to increase my enjoyment in study has been found.

Comment: @Robby zhu If "steps" or "ways" is plural, then the verb form must be "have", not "has": "*Ways to increase my enjoyment in study **have** been found.*" That is grammatically valid. But I see no advantage to the passive voice here, and would advise against using it unless there was some particular reason to use it.